# ¿Porque no carga mi Dashboard de Google Chart?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, google-chart-api

Este es mi codigo:
Estoy que programo en C# asp.net

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'controls'] });

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%=Dashboard()%>
            );

            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

            var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'filter_div',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Monto'                  
                }

            });

            var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'PieChart',
                'containerId': 'chart_div',
                'options': {
                    'width': 300,
                    'height': 300,
                    'pieSliceText': 'value',
                    'legend': 'right'
                }
            });


            dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);
            dashboard.draw(data);

     }
```

Extraigo los datos de SQL server:

```
protected string Dashboard()
        {

            SqlConnection conexionSQL = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-CSI0N6I\FREDDY;Initial Catalog=apci5; Integrated Security = True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT D.DESCRIPCION_DEPARTAMENTO , SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO) Monto  FROM Intervenciones I , Departamentos D, DETALLE_INTER_COOP DC " +
                "WHERE I.COD_DEPARTAMENTO = D.COD_DEPARTAMENTO AND I.COD_INTERVENCION = DC.COD_INTERVENCION GROUP BY D.DESCRIPCION_DEPARTAMENTO " +
                "ORDER BY D.DESCRIPCION_DEPARTAMENTO ";

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conexionSQL;
            conexionSQL.Open();

            DataTable datos = new DataTable();
            datos.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            conexionSQL.Close();

            string strDatos;
            strDatos = "[['Departamentos','Monto'], ";

            foreach (DataRow dr in datos.Rows)
            {
                strDatos = strDatos + "[";
                strDatos = strDatos + "'" + dr[0] + "'" + "," + dr[1];
                strDatos = strDatos + "],";
            }


            strDatos = strDatos + "]";

            return strDatos;

        }
```

Y estos son los divs

```
<div id="dashboard_div">

                             <div id="filter_div"></div>

                             <div id="chart_div" ></div>

                           </div>
```

Al correr la pagina web, no me carga el grafico.
Estoy usando multiview para mostrar diferentes tipos de graficos, me funcionan 3 graficos, y al momento de hacer un dashboard es la unica que no me carga. Ya he probado el ejemplo que pone Google Chart y si funciona, pero mi version no.
Creo que puede ser al momento de extraer los datos del sql server 2014.

Esta es una imagen de como me deberia salir :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDIT: Esto es lo que me sale como error en la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son mis datos que paso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El numero pasa con (,) en el array 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi solucion momentanea es convertir los decimales a enteros, eso lo hago en la misma consulta.
EJEMPLO:

**PASO DE** 
 
SELECT DESCRIPCION_DEPARTAMENTO, (SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO)) Monto FROM  .....
--->(SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO))

**A**

SELECT DC.DESCRIPCION_DEPARTAMENTO, CAST((ROUND(SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO), 0, 0)) AS INT) Monto  FROM ......
-----> CAST((ROUND(SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO), 0, 0))

Comment: Tienes algún error en la consola del navegador? Algún 404 u otro en la pestaña de red?

Comment: No nada, carga toda la pagina mas no el grafico, me sale solo un cuadro rojo que no recuerdo que dice, ni bien llegue a mi casa agrego lo que me sale.

Comment: Revisa en la consola y en la pestaña de red, en alguna parte debería de registrarse algún error. Otra opción usa Sentry.io

Comment: Me sale "One or more participants failed to draw()" en rojo. Reitero que el ejemplo que da google chart si me funciona pero no cuando yo lo hago con otros datos sacados de sql server

Comment: Parecería que entonces es en los datos que estás pasando al draw.

Comment: Acabo de subir poner una imagen de como son mis datos, ya he realizado otros graficos pero no con el monto de la tabla. Cuando pongo manualmente los datos y escribo los  montos con decimales 100.23 por ejemplo si funciona pero no jalando de la base de datos.

Comment: Esos datos se ven bien en el SSMS te diría, pero el string que estás construyendo a mano, ¿lo entiende en JavaScript como una colección de objetos, o se queda como un string?

Comment: Esos datos se ven bien en el SSMS te diría, pero el string que estás construyendo a mano, ¿lo entiende en JavaScript como una colección de objetos, o se queda como un string?

Comment: Acabo de correr la pagina web instruccion por instruccion y me sale que al momento de cargar el dato a array en ves de pasar 1000.13 pasa 1000,13 con coma ese crees que seria el problema?

Comment: Sí es muy probable que ese es el punto, como se están serializando en la cadena que pasas a JS los datos tenía base, y por eso la librería de charts no los entiende

Comment: Entonces como crees que pueda solucionarlo? , osea se que debo hacer algo que haga que esos datos lleguen con punto (.) y no con com (,) pero como?

Comment: Encontre la solucion , no se si es la correcta pero funciona. Convertir en el sql el decimal a entero asi ya no hay problemas de la (,) y (.)

Comment: Perfecto! Comparte tu solución como respuesta bien detallada (si fue un simple cambio de algún código o agregar algunas líneas con eso basta y explicado brevemente). Y marcas tu propia respuesta como la solución. Por tu esfuerzo y compartir la respuesta al final, te llevas ambos bonos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi solución momentánea es convertir los decimales a enteros, eso lo hago en la misma consulta.

 EJEMPLO:

 PASO DE

 SELECT DESCRIPCION_DEPARTAMENTO, **(SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO))** Monto FROM .....

 --->**(SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO))**

 A

 SELECT DC.DESCRIPCION_DEPARTAMENTO, **CAST((ROUND(SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO), 0, 0)) AS INT)** Monto FROM ......

 -----> **CAST((ROUND(SUM(DC.PRESUPUESTO), 0, 0))**

Debido a que los datos que extraía del sql al c# asp.net pasaban de 100.10 a 100,10 y no se porque pasaba esto así que decidí convertirlo a entero y listo.

Comment: Qué interesante, muy creativa tu solución